# Oracle SQL - Outer join based on concat

Tags: sql, oracle, join, outer-join

I need to cross join two tables but the joining conditions are:

```
Select FutureInventory.Item,
       To_Number(Concat(Location, Channel_Id)) Location,
  From V_CUST_FUTURE_INV_POSITION FutureInventory,
       xx_Item_Loc_Info_V         ItemLoc
 Where FutureInventory.Item(+) = ItemLoc.Item
   And To_Number(Concat(Location, Channel_Id))(+) = ItemLoc.Loc;
```

I want to outer join the column To_Number(Concat(Location, Channel_Id)) with ItemLoc.Loc
where to put the (+) sign

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic would all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use explicit join syntax - the old `(+)` is hard to read and easy to get wrong. Second, use the `||` operator instead of the `CONCAT` function - again, easier to read. So we end up with

```
Select FutureInventory.Item,
       To_Number(Location || Channel_Id) Location,
  From xx_Item_Loc_Info_V ItemLoc
  LEFT OUTER JOIN V_CUST_FUTURE_INV_POSITION FutureInventory,
    ON FutureInventory.Item = ItemLoc.Item And
       To_Number(Location || Channel_Id) = ItemLoc.Loc
```

Answer (score 0):

To do an outer join in Oracle, you use the appropriate `JOIN` type -- just as in all other databases.  I think the logic you want is:

```
select FutureInventory.Item,
       To_Number(Concat(Location, Channel_Id)) as Location,
from xx_Item_Loc_Info_V ItemLoc LEFT JOIN
     V_CUST_FUTURE_INV_POSITION FutureInventory,
     on FutureInventory.Item = ItemLoc.Item AND
        To_Number(Concat(Location, Channel_Id)) = ItemLoc.Loc;
```